# ASP.NET - How to get assembly from virtual path in custom IResourceProvider implementation

Tags: asp.net, .net-assembly, virtual-path

I'm developing custom local resource provider implementation, which should supply resource values from resources located in App_LocalResources folders, but the resources should be compiled as embedded. So no resx files will stay in web app folder, which default LocalResXResourceProvider expects.

The problem is I need to get to assembly with the embedded resources from virtual path and I'm not able to figure out what ASP.NET class use to translate virtual path to corresponding assembly. I was looking into decompiled sources of LocalResXResourceProvider and BuildManager, but all the things are internal. I wasn't able to get the assembly even using LocalResXResourceProvider.GetLocalResourceAssembly() through reflection - it just returns null when I deployed the application to clear folder without resx files in place. It works when resx files are present though...

Comment: hmm.. maybe BuildManager.GetCompiledType(virtualPath).BaseType.Assembly is way to go

Comment: this isn't viable solution, because BuildManager.GetCompiledType() compiles the target every time it's invoked

Comment: I don't think there's any solution to the problem at all ;(